# How to Click on a Hidden Link with BeautifulSoup or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download a file using Selenium and BeautifulSoup, but am running into some issues with the way the website is set up. I can see there is a table object containing the link I want deep in the code, but I'm running into difficulties actually instructing BeautifulSoup and Selenium to actually navigate that far and find the link. https://www.theice.com/clear-us/risk-management#margin-rates is the website and I want to download the Margin Scanning File.

```
hdr={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
req=urllib.request.Request(url,headers=hdr)
icepage=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
htmlitem=icepage.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlitem,'lxml')
divs=soup.find('div',{'class':'sticky-header__main'}) 
print(divs.findChild().find('div',{'class':'row'}).find('div',{'class':'1-main true-grid-10'}).find_all('div')[2])
```

From there divs.findChild().find('div',{'class':'row'}).find('div',{'class':'1-main true-grid-10'}).find_all('div')[2] is the closest I have gotten to selecting the next div that has id='content-5485eefe-b105-49ed-b1ac-7e9470d29262' and I want to drill down that to the ICUS_MARGIN_SCANNING csv in the table five or six further div levels below that.

With Selenium I'm even further lost where I've been trying variations of driver.find_element_by_link_text('Margin Scanning') and getting nothing back.

Any help with accessing that table and the ICUS_Margin_scanning file would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used f12=> network tab and found this [page](https://www.theice.com/marginrates/ClearUSMarginParameterFiles.shtml?getParameterFileTable&category=Current&_=1600177346754) so here u go

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
BASE_API_URL='https://www.theice.com'
r=requests.get(f'https://www.theice.com/marginrates/ClearUSMarginParameterFiles.shtml?getParameterFileTable&category=Current&_={int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()*1000)}')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,features='lxml')
margin_scanning_link=BASE_API_URL+soup.find_all("a", string="Margin Scanning")[0].attrs['href']
margin_scanning_file=requests.get(margin_scanning_link)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!